# Irrationality of $\alpha$ the fine-structure constant.

Tags: mathematical-physics

Is the fine-structure constant rational, or irrational? I have asked this question on the physics stack exchange, but I want to get some mathematicians' perspectives as well.

Comment: It is absurd to speak in these terms about **experimental** physics constants.

Comment: Indeed: we don't know any physical constant exactly, only to several decimal places. And any rounded-off number's several decimal places is consistent with being rational or irrational. It's not even clear it's consistent to talk about the *exact* value of a physical constant even in theory.

Answer (score 5):

There is no generally accepted mathematical formula for the fine structure constant.  It may not even be a constant: see e.g. [work of J.K. Webb et al.](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.107.191101)